# I learned that in C language char type ranges from -128 to 127, but it doesn't seem like that

Tags: c, char, signed, integer-promotion, internal-representation

This might be a very basic problem, but I couldn't manage to.
Here is what I am working with.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c1, c2;
    int s;
    c1 = 128;
    c2 = -128;

    s = sizeof(char);

    printf("size of char: %d\n", s);
    printf("c1: %x, c2: %x\n", c1, c2);
    printf("true or false: %d\n", c1 == c2);
}
```

The result is like this.

```sh
size of char: 1
c1: ffffff80, c2: ffffff80
true or false: 1
```

i assigned the value 128 to signed(normal) char type, but it didn't overflow.

In additon, c1 and c2 both seems to hold 4bytes, and -128 and 128 are the same value.

How can I understand these facts? I need your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: What is twos complement of a 4 byte integer of -128?

Comment: I think you're seeing [promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions) and sign extension.

Comment: I'm confused by your statement.  In this code, you assigned 128 to a signed char type, and it did overflow.  This is consistent with your expectation that the range is from -128 to 127.

Comment: 1) `char` much provide a minimum or -128..127 or a minimum of 0..255. They can provide much more. (There's a system with 32-bit chars.)

Comment: 2) `%x` requires an `unsigned int`. Your `char` is being promoted.

Comment: You already say in your title that the range is `-128 to 127` so why are you trying to use `(+)128`?

Comment: @ikegami I believe the minimum range of `char` if signed is -127..127 according to the standard.

Comment: @Christian Gibbons, oh yes, of course, to accomodate 1's complement systems

Comment: just use the correct printf format `%hhx` 128 does not fit in char and it is an integer overflow which is an UB.

Comment: @ikegami Or sign-and-magnitude.

Comment: agongji, WIth `c2 = -128;`, what did you expect to happen? If code went on, what value did you expect in `c2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `c1 = 128;`, 128 does not fit in the signed eight-bit `char` that your C implementation uses. 128 is converted to `char` per C 2018 6.5.16.1 2: “the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression…”

The conversion is implementation-defined, per 6.3.1.3 3: “Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.” Your C implementation converted 128, which is 10000000<sub>2</sub> as an unsigned binary numeral, to −128, which is represented with the same bits when using two’s complement for signed binary. Thus, the result is that `c1` contains the value −128.

In `printf("c1: %x, c2: %x\n", c1, c2);`, `c1` is converted to an `int`. This is because the rules for calling functions with `...` parameters are to apply the default argument promotions to the corresponding arguments, per 6.5.2.2 7: “The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments.”

The default argument promotions include the integer promotions, per 6.5.2.2 6. When the range of `char` is narrower than `int`, as it is in most C implementations, the integer promotions convert a `char` to an `int`, per 6.3.1.1 2: “If an `int` can represent all values of the original type…, the value is converted to an `int`…”

Thus, in `printf("c1: %x, c2: %x\n", c1, c2);`, an `int` value of −128 is passed as the second argument. Your C implementation uses 32-bit two’s complement for `int`, in which −128 is represented with the bits 11111111111111111111111110000000, which we can express in hexadecimal as ffffff80.

The format string specifies a conversion using `%x`. The proper argument type for `%x` is `unsigned int`. However, your C implementation has accepted the `int` and reinterpreted its bits as an `unsigned int`. Thus, the bits 11111111111111111111111110000000 are converted to the string “ffffff80”.

This explains why “ffffff80” is printed. It is not because `c1` has four bytes but because it was converted to a four-byte type before being passed to `printf`. Further, the conversion of a negative value to that four-byte type resulted in four bytes with many bits set.

Regarding `c1 == c2` evaluating to true (1), this is simply because `c1` was given the value −128 as explained above, and `c2 = -128;` also assigns the value −128 to `c2`, so `c1` and `c2` have the same value.

Comment: Your explanation helped me a lot to clear the fog in my brain. Now I have learned   integral conversion, promotion and how to use %x identifier. I need to learn to read  implementation-definition. language-feature.  Do programmers generally look up the web page like (http://www.dii.uchile.cl/~daespino/files/Iso_C_1999_definition.pdf) every time they need to confirm the language-feature? anyway, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @agongji That copy is probably, strictly spoken, a copyright violation. Publicly available and usually sufficient are the drafts, listed at https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/links. But yes, many of the posters here (probably those who earn an income as developers) own a copy of the ISO standard, I suppose, together with other text books. Most technical C language questions have been properly answered on SO though. Technical errors tend to be corrected quickly and reliably here. But admittedly, sometimes it's unclear what to search for ("default argument promotions"!?).

Comment: @agongji: Good practitioners learn the rules well enough that they do not need to look up the rules often, and/or develop code-writing habits that avoid needing to look up the rules, and they do look up the rules when necessary. After a time, one becomes familiar with various documents so that finding things within them becomes faster.

Answer (score 2):

The type `char` can behave as the type `signed char` or as the type `unsigned char` depending on a compiler option or default settings of the compiler.

In your case the type `char` behaves as the type `signed char`. In this case `CHAR_MIN` is equal to `-128` and `CHAR_MAX` is equal to `127`.

So an object of the type `char` can not hold the positive number 128. Internally this value has the following hexadecimal representation `0x80`. So stored in an object of the type `char` it is interpreted as a negative value because the sign bit is set. This negative value is `-128`.

So after these statements

```
c1 = 128;
c2 = -128;
```

the both objects have the same value equal to `-128`.

And the output

```
c1: ffffff80, c2: ffffff80
```

of this call

```
printf("c1: %x, c2: %x\n", c1, c2);
```

shows that the both objects `c1` and `c2` promoted to the type `int`  have the same representation of a negative value.

Pay attention to that it is implementation-defined behavior to assign an object of the signed type with a positive value that can not be represented in the object.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Raising a signal means that behavior is undefined. For example you can get a trap value.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your explanation is very simple and totally makes sense. I guess I understand. Char type is 8 bit and can hold 128, thats' why the overflow error doesn't occur and 128 just gets converted to -128 according to implementation-definition.

Answer (score 1):

In the statement

```
printf("c1: %x, c2: %x\n", c1, c2);
```

`%x` expects an argument of type `unsigned int`, so the values of `c1` and `c2` are being promoted from `char` to `unsigned int`, with the leading bit extended.  To print the numeric value of an `unsigned char` as hex, you need to use the `hh` length modifier in the conversion:

```
printf("c1: %hhx, c2: %hhx\n", c1, c2 );
```

As for the values that can be represented in a `char`, it's a little more complicated than that.

The encodings for members of the *basic character set*<sup>1</sup> are guaranteed to be non-negative.  Encodings for additional characters may be negative or non-negative.

Thus, depending on the implementation, a plain `char` may represent values in at least the range `[-128..127]` (assuming two's complement representation) ***or*** `[0..255]`.  I say "at least" since `CHAR_BIT` may be more than 8 (there are historical systems that used 9-bit bytes and 36-bit words).  A `signed char` will represent values in at least the range `[-128..127]` (again, assuming two's complement).

Assuming `char` is signed and 8 bits, then assigning 128 to `c1` leads to *signed integer overflow* and the behavior on that is *undefined*, meaning the compiler and execution environment aren't required to handle it in any particular way.  *Any* result is "correct" as far as the language definition is required, whether it's the result you expected or not.

---

1. Upper- and lowercase Latin alphabet, decimal digits, 29 graphical characters, whitespace and control characters (line feed, form feed, tab, etc.).

Comment: There is no promotion to unsigned int here. `c1`,  `c2` undergo default argument promotions and end up (in this case) being `int`s, and since they do not have a positive value, then the behaviour is undefined when used with stdarg macros as unsigned ints.

Answer (score 0):

Here its explained: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

If -128 and 128 and all numbers in between were represented with a byte, we would have 257 numbers in that set. We however dont, its just 256.

Its mapped as follows decimal: [0..127,-128..-1] => [0b00000000..0b11111111]. Note that the first bit becomes 1 at -128, happy accident ;).

Also your string formatting is incorrect, your compiler should warn you, %x expects 4 bytes! If you take into account what I said earlier then you see that 0x80 is indeed 0b10000000.